# Copy Notepad.exe from system folder to desktop and run it

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, notepad

on some Windows 7 machine, `notepad.exe` can launch from desktop
but lots of Windows 7 machine, no matter x86 or x64, it cannot start. no error no warning, just silently quit, like you never click on it before.

Is there any policy or system setting to block this?

I thought it is quite common to copy `notepad.exe` to anyplace and run it, lots of Windows installer sample do this.

Comment: I've never experienced this behavior. Are you sure you're not doing something else wrong ?

Comment: Yes, we tried on several machine inside company. some machine can do the copy and run, some machine copy and run failed. so funny.

Comment: I think it's much more likely that a "Windows installer" is actually creating a _shortcut_ to notepad.exe on the desktop or in the Start menu, rather than actually copying the Notepad executable itself.  I can't think of a good reason why copying the executable would somehow be better than creating a shortcut.  How are you creating the desktop icon?

Comment: Did you try creating a shortcut by right clicking anywhere on the Desktop, choosing create new item, new shortcut and pointing the source to C:\Windows\Systems32\notepad.exe with whatever name you wish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you probably shouldn't copy the `notepad.exe` file around, when you do you need to also copy the mui files from `xx-yy\notepad.exe.mui` to the same relative location (where `xx-yy` is the language code such as `en-US`).

Comment: Reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/the-case-of-the-notepad-that-wouldn-t-run/ba-p/723535